# Почему для запуска Angular приложения нужен сервер?

Tags: angular, сборка, angular-routing

Изучая Angular6+ делаю небольшое SPA приложение. Решил скомпилировать и попробовать запустить на другом ноутбуке. Нагуглил команду `ng build --prod`, выполнил, в появившейся папке `dist` запустил файл `index.html` и словил ошибку `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///E:/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL`

Снова стал гуглить и узнал, что в SPA есть 2 способа маршрутизации: `HashLocationStrategy` и `PathLocationStrategy`, почитал про них [тут](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-location-strategies/) и [тут](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/), понял в чем разница между ними.
Добавив `, { useHash: true }` в метод `forRoot()` - поменял стратегию в приложении. Перекомпилировал и открыл `index.html` файл, приложение работало, но пути к "ассетам" почему-то начинались от коня диска, поэтому картинки не отображались.

В тех статьях я прочитал:

> when you ask from http://www.example.com/ProductList, the Web server must redirect it to index.html and return the request. Then in the Front-end Angular will read the URL and dynamically load the ProductList component.

То есть, как я понимаю, если мы открываем приложение на какой-то странице, идет GET запрос на сервер для получения этой страницы, т.к. у нас SPA, сервер не отдает эту html страницу (ProductList.html, потому что ее нет), а отдает `index.html` со всеми скриптами, стилями и т.д. Подгруженные скрипты смотрят наш URL в браузере и на его основе генерируют нужную страницу.

**Вот что мне не понятно:** когда я использую `PathLocationStrategy`, я скомпилировал проект с помощью `ng build`, либо `ng build --prod`, а потом открыл файл `index.html`, теоретически подгруженные по ссылкам из `<head></head>` скрипты должны посмотреть путь в браузере, понять, что открыт "корень" приложения и отобразить домашнюю страницу, но вместо это отображается белый лист и ошибка в консоли браузера. Почему так?

**UPDATE_1:**

Когда я открываю скомпилированный `index.html`, то в браузере отображается путь `file:///D:/anyfolders/index.html`, дальше браузер читает этот файл и натыкается на строку `<base href="/">`, которая, как я понимаю, "говорит", что нулевые координаты/путь отсчета это корень диска и браузер уже начиная от корня диска искать последующие файлы, не находит их в корне и выкидывает ошибку. Если удалить/закомментировать строку `<base href="/">`, тогда все файлы подгрузятся нормально, но приложение не будет работать, т.к. `<base href="/">` является жизненно необходимым для него критерием.

Если же все нужные файлы перенести в корень диска, то при открытии `index.html` отображается домашняя страница приложения, а так же ошибка `Unhandled Navigation Error:` в консоли браузера. Когда навожу курсор на ссылку, сделанную через директиву `routerLink` в проекте, то в браузере слева внизу отображается путь ссылки как `file:///D:/about`, где `about`, это значение, которое было в `routerLink` в проекте. Если нажать на тег с такой ссылкой, то в браузере ничего не происходит вообще. Опять таки - непонятное поведение.

Comment: меня очень смущают ваш вопрос, вы документацию вовсе не открывали? `скрипты должны посмотреть путь в браузере, понять, что открыт "корень" приложения и отобразить домашнюю страницу, но вместо это отображается белый лист и ошибка в консоли браузера` - не должны, вы в дебри залезли, читайте документацию, там все детально описано

Comment: Потому что клиент-серверная архитектура подразумевает под собой наличие сервера... и клиентов, которые будут к нему обращаться по IP адресу. Поэтому вам нужна программа, которые эти самые запросы будет обрабатывать, даже если они уходят на localhost к самому себе.

Comment: @overthesanity, я, естественно посмотрел документацию https://angular.io/guide/deployment , но не нашел там разъяснения, почему для запуска приложения нужен сервер, увидел только инструкцию как запустить приложение.

Comment: @AlexKrass, а если приложение не общается с сервером. Например тот же "Tours of Heroes" из документации, который никак не взаимодействует с сервером, а только с DOM. Почему скомпилированный "Тур по героям" не может отображаться/работать без сервера?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что он должен работать без сервера? наверное потому что браузер ищет js файлы в корне? потому что наверное так путь прописан?

Comment: @overthesanity, я думал, что приложение может работать без сервера, потому что это набор html, css, js и т.д. файлов, которые никак не общаются с сервером. Да, браузер ищет js файлы в корне диска, но если закомментировать строку `<base href="/">`, тогда все файлы подгружаются, но приложение не работает и появляется ошибка `Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.`. Это никак не проясняет ситуацию.

Даже если переместить все нужные файлы в корень диска, расскоментировать base тэг, то ошибка `Unhandled Navigation Error:`

Comment: я не вижу смысла на данном этапе лезть в эти дебри ИМХО :)

Comment: @overthesanity, я все же хочу прояснить вопрос. Я пробовал перемещать все файлы в корень диска и открыть `index.html`, в таком случае отображалсь домашняя страница, в консоли браузера была ошибка `Unhandled Navigation Error:` и при наведении курсора на ссылку, на которой был навешен `routerLink`, Chrome слева отображал путь от корня диска, типо `file:///D:/about`, где `about` это то, что было в `routerLink`.

Comment: @Drovosek Angular внутри себя изначально заточен на работу с сервером и все обращения внутри все равно идут через XHR. Даже в простом приложении он подгружает нужные ему скрипты (начальная страница). И здесь у вас начинаются потенциальные проблемы, поскольку XHR не может обратиться к локальной системе. Следовательно внутри Angular все рушится и приложение не работает. В теории можно все перелопатить и отвязать от сервера, но оно того не стоит и нужен ли тогда вообще angular.

Comment: @AlexKrass, звучит правдоподобно, я в это верю :). Теперь вроде бы этот вопрос отвязался от моей головы, большое спасибо! Если хотите, напишите это как ответ, я помечу его как лучший.

Comment: @AlexKrass > `Angular внутри себя изначально заточен на работу с сервером` - где это можно прочитать, можете дать ссылку? буду весьма благодарен

Comment: Не, ответ давать не хочу, поскольку только поверхностно сейчас заглянул во внутрь angular и переписав половину ссылок вылетел в CORS with origin 'null' ошибки при обращении XHR к ///file (@overthesanity, отсюда вывод, никаких других источников). Возможно есть какой-либо способ запустить без сервера, но из коробки я этого не нашел. В любом случае мой ответ может быть ошибочен, я допускаю этот вариант. Вот тут к примеру идет целое обсуждение по этому поводу и сборка через webpack: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/D9-Wh0NjMSY

Comment: @AlexKrass схема //file это не XHR (см. rfc8089)

Comment: @overthesanity зато обращается он к нему через XHR)) Ошибка и источник недвусмысленно на это намекают: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///.../src/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.